# Alamofire URLRequestConvertible not able to escape "/" in encoding

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession, url-encoding

I am using URLRequestConvertible for Alamofire.

I have a GET request were my url has one "/" which needs to be escaped.

Please see below example where "NameToPass/23"  has a "/" now.

When I use URLEncoding.default the "/" is not encoded but the server is expecting it to encode with **%2F**

But lets say If I encode it while  making the relativepath

```
"NameToPass/23".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)
```

the Alamofire encode it twice and make it  "NameToPass%252F23"

Below is the sample code for the same.

```
    let encoding: ParameterEncoding = {
        switch self {
        case . getItemDetails:
            return URLEncoding.default
         }
    }()



  let url: URL = {
        let relativePath: String?
        switch self {

        case .getItemDetails(let listName):

                relativePath = "/mainAction/" + "NameToPass/23" 


          var url = URL(string: BaseURL)!

        if let relativePath = relativePath { url = url.appendingPathComponent(relativePath) }
        return url
    }()
```

Any Hint in right direction will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you need only `NameToPass/23` escaped? Then try

```
relativePath = "/mainAction/" + "NameToPass/23".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)
```

Comment: please see my updated answer. As alamofire encode twice the "/"